# Additional calculations after creating a pivot table on select columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table using this code:

```
q2=q1.pivot(index='state', columns='year', values='wtrate')
```

where I reshape a dataset that was long (each state had 10 observations for each year) and I save the values from the variable wtrate.  Now, I want to calculate a CAGR for different time periods (let's say 2008 to 2019 and also 2014-2019) and add it as columns. (CAGR is (End Value / Beginning Value)^(1/n)-1 where n is the number of years).  It seems like I should create a function and apply it using aggfunc but I'm not sure how to do so given that I'm not applying the function to all values in the table, but selecting based on the "columns" which are no longer columns.  (That leads me to another question, which is: can I select the columns by year? Why does this pivot table format prevent me from doing that-- for example, saying q2.2008 or q2['2008'] lead to errors.)

Thanks for your help.
See below for pivot table.

```
      year  2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2017    2018    2019
state                                               
Connecticut 14.377595   16.698319   18.170756   19.469117   21.618318   23.231428   24.135471   25.523063   26.424191   28.025954   35.782651   38.541251
Delaware    3.987193    4.816631    3.541428    3.744169    5.032608    6.912063    7.617630    8.013958    9.221290    11.234383   13.287280   14.908855
Illinois    9.297402    9.912991    9.694201    9.212093    10.322511   11.178365   17.523890   21.215137   21.982069   23.910823   24.702551   25.77111
```

Sorry the year is not properly aligned with the columns but I could not fix it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, could you rephrase it?

Comment: Please post some code to re-create the input: `df = pd.DataFrame({...})` Is the desired output the table you posted?

Comment: Are your years strings or numbers? Does `q2[2008]` work?

Comment: "q2.2008 or q2['2008'] lead to errors." What errors do they lead to?

Comment: Thanks for your questions and responses.  Yes, it turns out (I did not realize) that it matters whether the columns / years are strings or numbers.  So both busybear and Matt W. are correct in the implementation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
cagr = lambda df, start, end: (df[end]/df[start])**(1/((end-start)+1))-1

q2['CAGR_08'] = cagr(q2, 2008, 2019)
q2['CAGR_14'] = cagr(q2, 2014, 2019)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new dataframe `q3` as

```
  q3 = 1+q2.pct_change(axis = 1)
```

and do

```
  from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean
```

then you can get the CGAR for a period as

```
  gmean(q3.loc[state,beginning_year+1:ending_year])-1
```

However, make sure that your column names are cast as `int`.